# What's wrong with this PL/SQL Trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have this table, and I want to create a trigger on `Magazine`, that verifies "after insert" if the name of the `Magazine` inserted is either *Vogue* or *People*.

If it's not one of them, it gets deleted.

Table:

- MAGAZINE (ISBN, MAG_NOM, PRIX_Mois);

My trigger:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TMag
  AFTER INSERT ON Magazine
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  e EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  IF :new.mag_nom != 'Vogue' or :new.mag_nom != 'People' THEN
     DELETE Magazine WHERE ISBN = :new.ISBN;
    RAISE e;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN e THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('nom mag incorrecte');
END;
```

But the problem is my teacher told me:

> This is not suitable for every situation

I don't know what that means, can you please help me improve this trigger?

It seemed correct to me, what did I do wrong ?

Comment: This trigger is not suitable, because it is incorrect at all. You should have `ORA-04091: table <table name> is mutating, trigger/function may not see it`. You may use `check` constraint for this, it is much more clear.

Comment: @astentx Am only a beginner, so i don't understand you 100%. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a DML, convert the trigger into this

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TMag
  AFTER INSERT ON Magazine
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.mag_nom NOT IN ('Vogue','People') THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202,'nom mag incorrecte !');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

and you would get table is mutating error in this case due to using the table, on which the trigger is created, within the trigger's body.

Moreover it would be far better to add a check constraint than creating a trigger such as

```sql
ALTER TABLE abc
ADD CONSTRAINT cc_mag_nom
  CHECK (mag_nom IN ('Vogue','People'));
```

Comment: Thank you ! Can you please explain what i did wrong or what i should have done better to my code. Thanks again :)

Comment: you're welcome @Maoane , as I expressed, using the table within the trigger body would raise a mutating table error due to simultaneous operation on the same table, and using a trigger will probably yield a maintenance  such that you should keep it valid forever. Rather use a check constraint within the table's definition.